# occurrence of specific character in multiple strings

Tags: python, string, list

The multiple strings that needed to be searched are stored in a file values.txt (the Input File) which for example contains information as follows:

```
XXVVXXVVVVVXXVXVV
VXVXVXXXXXVVVVXXX
VVVVXXVVVXVVXXXXX
XVXXXVVVXXVXXVXVX
VXXVVXVXXVVVXXVVX
XVXVXXXXXXXXVVVVV
VVVXXVVXVXVVXXVVX
XVXXVXXXVVXXXVXXX
VVVVXXXXXXVXVXXXX
VXVVXVVXVVXVVVVXV
VVXVXVXXVVXXVVXVV
VVXVVXXVVXXXVVVXV
XVXVVVVXVXVVVVVVV
VXXVVXVXVXVVXXXVX
XVVVVXVXVXXXXVVVX
VXXVVVVXXVXVXVVVX
```

I'm trying to count the occurrence of V in every line for index[x], x being the position of a character in every line.

For example, there are 10 "V" in every first character of the lines. 10 "V" in the second character of the lines and 7 "V" in the third character of the lines.

I have already tried enlisting the lines en counting the amount of "V" in every line, but i'm not getting anyware. Any suggestions?

expected answer: [10, 10, 7, 12, 8, 6, 10, 4, 10, 6, 9, 8, 7, 11, 8, 10, 6]

Comment: please provide the example as **text** and the matching expected output

Comment: Also, you could show us some code you've been working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and  a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

out = [Counter(col)['V'] for col in zip(*text.split('\n'))]
```

Alternative without import:

```
out = [len([c for c in col if c == 'V']) for col in zip(*text.split('\n'))]
```

output: `[10, 10, 7, 12, 8, 6, 10, 4, 10, 6, 9, 8, 7, 11, 8, 10, 6]`

used input:

```
text = '''XXVVXXVVVVVXXVXVV
VXVXVXXXXXVVVVXXX
VVVVXXVVVXVVXXXXX
XVXXXVVVXXVXXVXVX
VXXVVXVXXVVVXXVVX
XVXVXXXXXXXXVVVVV
VVVXXVVXVXVVXXVVX
XVXXVXXXVVXXXVXXX
VVVVXXXXXXVXVXXXX
VXVVXVVXVVXVVVVXV
VVXVXVXXVVXXVVXVV
VVXVVXXVVXXXVVVXV
XVXVVVVXVXVVVVVVV
VXXVVXVXVXVVXXXVX
XVVVVXVXVXXXXVVVX
VXXVVVVXXVXVXVVVX'''
```